# Como poner condicion en query de MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tego el siguiente query que funciona tal y como debe hacerlo.

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM datos WHERE intervalo in ($in) and fecha_hora >= '$dateini' AND fecha_hora <= '$datefin' and archivo in ($arch) and hora between $horain and $horafin", $db2);
```

Mi pregunta es, como puedo poner una condicion donde `intervalo` cuando reciba `$in` e `$in` tenga el valor de ***15seg*** este ponga las horas tanto de inicio como final en 00:00:00 y de lo contrario si es otro valor diferente a ***15seg*** que ejecute el query que se puso al principio.

Comment: Lo mejor sería tener 2 queries y ejecutarlos por separado. Sino, puedes utilizar siempre el buen `OR`: `WHERE (($in = 15 AND <condiciones cuando $in = 15 segundos>) OR ($in != 15 AND <condiciones cuando $in != 15 segundos>)) AND <resto de tus condiciones>`

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo único que quieres cambiar de la consulta es el valor de `$horain` y `$horafin`, dependiendo del valor de `$in`.

Asumo que el valor de `$in` está expresado en segundos y es un solo valor (no es un arreglo con valores o string con una lista de valores separadas con comas).

En ese caso hacer `intervalo in ($in)` se puede reemplazar por `intervalo = $in`.

También asumo que los string de fecha tiene formato DD/MM/YYYY (ej: 31/12/2015).

Una posible solución:

```
//Si $in es igual a 15, la hora inicio y fin se ponen en 00:00:00
if($in == 15){
    $horaInicial= '00:00:00';
    $horaFin= '00:00:00';
}else{
    $horaInicial= $horain;
    $horaFin= $horafin;
}


$query= "SELECT * FROM datos ";
$query.= " WHERE intervalo = $in and "; 
$query.= " fecha_hora >= STR_TO_DATE('$dateini','%d/%m%/%Y) AND ";
$query.= " fecha_hora <= STR_TO_DATE('$datefin','%d/%m%/%Y) and ":
$query.= " archivo in ($arch) and ";
$query.= " hora between STR_TO_DATE($horaInicial,'%h:%i:%s) and STR_TO_DATE($horaFin,'%h:%i:%s)";

$result2 = mysql_query($query, $db2);
```

La función `STR_TO_DATE` transforma un string en un tipo datetime, date o time dependiendo del formato pasado. La utilizo porque no siempre el casteo de string a date, time o datetime funciona según lo que uno esperaría. Más info sobre la función [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Por otra parte, sólo a modo informativo, mysql_query forma parte la API original de MySQL la cual es desde PHP 5.5 se declaró, obsoleta. Del manual de PHP puede leerse:

> Advertencia
>
> Esta extensión fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP
>   7.0.0. En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones MySQLi o PDO_MySQL. Véase también la guía MySQL: elegir una API y sus P+F
>   relacionadas para más información. Alternatives to this function
>   include:
>
> ```
> mysqli_query()
> PDO::query()
> ```

Comment: hola que tal @el-asiduo, probe el codigo que sugeriste pero no arrojo los resultados

Comment: @Houdini la información depende de qué registros tienes en la tabla `datos`. Ayudaría a mejorar la respuesta si editas tu pregunta y agregas un ejemplo de los datos que tienes en la tabla y cuáles son los resultados que esperas obtener en cada caso.